# sqoop java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to export a table from hive to oracle database.

The table in hive I try to export from

```
CREATE TABLE `db.to_oracle`(
  `ctn` string,
  `platform_code` string,
  `sum` double,
  `days_ctn` int,
  `mtr_comments` string,
  `imsi` string,
  `ban` int,
  `price_plan` string,
  `market_code` string,
  `currency` string,
  `balance` string,
  `time_key` date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

My sqoop statement

```
sqoop export \
-D mapreduce.job.queuename=adhoc \
-D oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:secret \
--password pas \
--username user\
--export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/db.db/to_oracle/ \
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
--table database.oracle_table
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '9696278394S10.01dolg_neaktivnost#20170513_3#1#12.0525099318958479562895398812VSE1NIKORUR-9992017-05-13'
```

It seems sqoop doesn't recognize the delimiter or something. Why is that and how do I correct it?

Comment: What is the field delimiter in `db.to_oracle` table?  --input-fields-terminated-by `#` or `\t` ?

Comment: @dev It's `\t`. I solved it by recreating the table and specifying `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'` and using `;` as delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Delimiters, as you did not specify the delimiters in hive table, the default hive delimiters are:

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'

COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\002'

MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\003'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Change the delimiters either in hive table creation or in your sqoop job to resolve the issue.